# Audio only with MPMoviePlayerController on iO4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

When I play a video doing this:

```
    NSString *videoFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bacon" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilepath];
    MPMoviePlayerController *movie;
    movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    [movie play];
```

on 3.2, it works pefeectly. But if I switch the base SDK to 4.0 i only hear the sound of the movie.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any unusual messages on console?
If this is an "error" and not a bug in the SDK you should

Comment: Is this on the device or on the simulator?  Are you sure you are not getting a codec error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that adding this with your play command should improve matters for you:

[movie play] 
[movie setFullscreen:YES];
[self.view addSubview:movie.view];

Try testing this property as it sounds like the movie is playing but has not been set to fullscreen:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/fullscreen

This line of code is also of importance:
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movie];

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
//add frame works

 //   AVFoundation.framework
 //   MediaPlayer.framework
    [movie setFullscreen:YES]; 
    [self.view addSubview:movie.view];
    moviePlayer.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleDefault; 
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
     moviePlayer.repeatMode = YES;
```